# Where exactly git push--recurse-submodules=on-demand pushes commits?

Tags: git, git-submodules

Let's say I have git repo with submodules.

Let's say one of the submodules has branches `Br1` (currently checked out) and branch `Br2`.

- local `Br1` has commits: A->B
- remote `Br1` **has commits: A**
- local `Br2` has commits: A->B
- remote `Br2` has commits: A->B

in other words, local `Br1` is ahead:

```
git status
On branch v1.1.0_with_fixes
Your branch is ahead of 'origin/v1.1.0_with_fixes' by 1 commit.
  (use "git push" to publish your local commits)

nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

**BUT its local SHA exists on the remote in another branch**.

#### The question:

If I invoke `git  push--recurse-submodules=on-demand` (from the parent repo), what (if any) is pushed and where?

P.S.

Experiment shows that nothing is pushed at all... Which is confusing...

Answer (score 1):

With `--recurse-submodules=on-demand`, Git checks if the new submodule commits recorded in the superproject are reachable from *at least one remote-tracking branch* in the submodule, and pushes them if not. This could  [*] explain why nothing is pushed in your case, since remote branch `Br2` points to B.

This behaviour is not very well described in the [doc](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-push#Documentation/git-push.txt---recurse-submodulescheckon-demandonlyno), which states:

> If **check** is used Git will verify that all submodule commits that changed in the revisions to be pushed are available on at least one remote of the submodule. If any commits are missing the push will be aborted and exit with non-zero status. If **on-demand** is used all submodules that changed in the revisions to be pushed will be pushed.

As I wrote above, in fact they will only be pushed if they are not reachable from at least one remote-tracking branch in the submodule. This is implemented in [`submodule_needs_pushing`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/submodule.c#L1045-L1047), called from [`find_unpushed_submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/submodule.c#L1091-L1094), which is used by [`push_unpushed_submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/submodule.c#L1220), which implements `on-demand` (see [`transport_push`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/transport.c#L1393-L1417)).

[*] I write "could" because it's unclear from your post which commit is recorded in the superproject when you invoke `git push --recurse-submodules=on-demand`. If the submodule is in  "modified" state, then `--recurse-submodules=on-demand` does nothing. It's only if the recorded submodule commit is changed *in the superproject commits being pushed* that it comes into effect.

So, the answer to the first part of your question (what (if any) is pushed) is: Git determines a set of submodule commits, let's call them "new submodules commits" that are recorded in the superproject branch being pushed; if these "new submodule commits" are not already reachable by a remote-tracking branch in the submodule, they are pushed.

Note that the way Git determines the set of submodule commits to check is by examining all commits that change the submodule in the superproject branch being pushed, that are not already reachable by a remote-tracking branch *in the superproject* (see [`find_unpushed_submodules`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/bda494f4043963b9ec9a1ecd4b19b7d1cd9a0518/submodule.c#L1100-L1108)). So, if the submodule is changed in commits that are *already* reachable by a different superproject branch than the one being pushed to, they won't be pushed. I guess the assumption there is that this other branch was also pushed with `--recurse-submodules=on-demand`, and thus most likely the submodule commits are also already pushed.

---

Now for the other part of your question (where are the new submodule commits pushed), this is easier: if there are submodule commits to be pushed, **they are pushed to a branch in the submodule with the same name as the superproject branch being pushed, and to a remote with the same name as the submodule remote being pushed to**. This is the case since [06bf4ad1db](https://github.com/git/git/commit/06bf4ad1db92c32af38e16d9b7f928edbd647780) (push: propagate remote and refspec with --recurse-submodules, 2017-04-05) which went into Git 2.13. Only if a URL or filesystem path is given as remote in the `git push` invocation, then the default remote and refspec of the submodule are used.